# How to pass state array with multiple objects as a parameter to graphql mutation?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, react-sortable-hoc

I am creating an app that allows users to create lists (all data is stored on mongoDB and accessed via Apollo GraphQL); each list has a property, listItems, an array that stores all the items in the list.

Currently I am now able to move the listItems around and have them setState in an array accessed via state.items as shown [in this video](https://i.imgur.com/Jl1eARc.mp4).  The list movement is controlled by components found within [react-sortable-hoc library](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc)

The issue I am having is taking this state.items array of listItems and using a mutation to have the state.items array replace the backend respective list.listItems array in the database.

I believe I may have not properly setup the typeDefs for input ListItems (I was getting **Error: The type of Mutation.editListItems(listItems:) must be Input Type but got: [ListItem]!.** so I changed it to input instead of type which may be an issue?)

Lastly I attempt to call the editListItems mutation in the RankList functional component below (contained in RankList.js) 'onChange'.  I am not sure where the issue and when moving items, it seems the mutation is not called.  Please advise (let me know if I should include more info)!

Overall, I wonder if the following could be an issue:

- *Is the typeDef for editListItems properly implemented?*
- *Is onChange the right thing to use here?*
- *Am I calling the mutation properly (in RankList component)?*
- *Am I properly passing state.items in the editListItems mutation (in RankList component)?*

**typeDefs.js**

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server");

//schema

module.exports = gql`
  type List {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    listItems: [ListItem]!
    comments: [Comment]!
    likes: [Like]!
    likeCount: Int!
    commentCount: Int!
  }
  type ListItem {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    body: String!
  }
  input ListItems {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    body: String!
  }
  type Comment {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    body: String!
  }
  type Like {
    id: ID!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
  }
  type User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    token: String!
    username: String!
    createdAt: String!
  }
  input RegisterInput {
    username: String!
    password: String!
    confirmPassword: String!
    email: String!
  }
  type Query {
    getLists: [List]
    getList(listId: ID!): List
  }
  type Mutation {
    register(registerInput: RegisterInput): User!
    login(username: String!, password: String!): User!
    createList(title: String!): List!
    editListItems(listId: ID!, listItems: ListItems!): List!
    deleteList(listId: ID!): String!
    createListItem(listId: ID!, body: String!): List!
    deleteListItem(listId: ID!, listItemId: ID!): List!
    createComment(listId: ID!, body: String!): List!
    deleteComment(listId: ID!, commentId: ID!): List!
    likeList(listId: ID!): List!
  },
  type Subscription{
    newList: List!
  }
`;
```

**list.js (resolvers)**

```
async editListItems(_, { listId, listItems }, context) {
      console.log("editListItems Mutation activated!");
      const user = checkAuth(context);

      const list = await List.findById(listId);

      if (list) {
        if (user.username === list.username) {
          list.listItems = listItems;
          await list.save();
          return list;
        } else {
          throw new AuthenticationError("Action not allowed");
        }
      } else {
        throw new UserInputError("List not found");
      }
    },
```

**RankList.js (List component shown in the video above)**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { useQuery, useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import moment from "moment";

import { AuthContext } from "../context/auth";
import { SortableContainer, SortableElement } from "react-sortable-hoc";
import arrayMove from "array-move";
import "../RankList.css";
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";

const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ value }) => (
  <li className="listLI">{value}</li>
));

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ items }) => {
  return (
    <ol className="theList">
      <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="ranklist"
        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
      >
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <SortableItem
            key={`item-${item.id}`}
            index={index}
            value={item.body}
          />
        ))}
      </CSSTransitionGroup>
    </ol>
  );
});

function RankList(props) {
  const listId = props.match.params.listId;
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const listItemInputRef = useRef(null);

  const [state, setState] = useState({ items: [] });
  const [listItem, setListItem] = useState("");

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FETCH_LIST_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      listId,
    },
    onError(err) {
      console.log(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);
      // setErrors(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.getList && data.getList.listItems) {
      setState(() => ({ items: data.getList.listItems }));
    }
  }, [data]);

  // const [state, setState] = useState({ items: data.getList.listItems });

  const [submitListItem] = useMutation(SUBMIT_LIST_ITEM_MUTATION, {
    update() {
      setListItem("");
      listItemInputRef.current.blur();
    },
    variables: {
      listId,
      body: listItem,
    },
  });

  const [editListItems] = useMutation(EDIT_LIST_ITEMS_MUTATION, {
    variables: {
      listId,
      listItems: state.items,
    },
  });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error..</p>;

  function deleteListCallback() {
    props.history.push("/");
  }

  function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {
    setState(({ items }) => ({
      items: arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    }));
    //THIS MAY BE WHERE THE ISSUE LIES
    editListItems();
  }

  let listMarkup;
  if (!data.getList) {
    listMarkup = <p>Loading list...</p>;
  } else {
    const {
      id,
      title,
      createdAt,
      username,
      listItems,
      comments,
      likes,
      likeCount,
      commentCount,
    } = data.getList;

    listMarkup = user ? (
      <div className="todoListMain">
        <div className="rankListMain">
          <div className="rankItemInput">
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <Form>
              <div className="ui action input fluid">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Choose rank item.."
                  name="listItem"
                  value={listItem}
                  onChange={(event) => setListItem(event.target.value)}
                  ref={listItemInputRef}
                />
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="ui button teal"
                  disabled={listItem.trim() === ""}
                  onClick={submitListItem}
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </Form>
          </div>
          <SortableList
            items={state.items}
            onSortEnd={onSortEnd}
            helperClass="helperLI"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className="todoListMain">
        <div className="rankListMain">
          <div className="rankItemInput">
            <h3>{props.title}</h3>
          </div>
          <SortableList
            items={listItems}
            onSortEnd={onSortEnd}
            helperClass="helperLI"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return listMarkup;
}

const EDIT_LIST_ITEMS_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation($listId: ID!, $listItems: ListItems!) {
    editListItems(listId: $listId, listItems: $listItems) {
      id
      listItems {
        id
        body
        createdAt
        username
      }
    }
  }
`;

const SUBMIT_LIST_ITEM_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation($listId: ID!, $body: String!) {
    createListItem(listId: $listId, body: $body) {
      id
      listItems {
        id
        body
        createdAt
        username
      }
      comments {
        id
        body
        createdAt
        username
      }
      commentCount
    }
  }
`;

const FETCH_LIST_QUERY = gql`
  query($listId: ID!) {
    getList(listId: $listId) {
      id
      title
      createdAt
      username
      listItems {
        id
        createdAt
        username
        body
      }
      likeCount
      likes {
        username
      }
      commentCount
      comments {
        id
        username
        createdAt
        body
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default RankList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

too many issues ... briefly:

> const [state, setState] = useState({ items: [] });

**Don't use `setState` in hooks ... it's missleading, `setState` is for class components.**

Use some meaningful name, f.e. `itemList`:

```
const [itemList, setItemList] = useState( [] ); // just array
```

Adjust query result saving:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (data && data.getList && data.getList.listItems) {
    // setState(() => ({ items: data.getList.listItems }));
    setItemList( data.getList.listItems );
  }
}, [data]);
```

Adjust sortable update handler:

```
const onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
  // this.setState(({items}) => ({
  //  items: arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex),
  // }));
  const newListOrder = arrayMove( itemList, oldIndex, newIndex);
  // console.log("array sorted", newListOrder );
  // update order in local state
  // kind of optimistic update
  setItemList( newListOrder );
  // update remote data
  editListItems( {
    variables: {
      listId,
      listItems: newListOrder,
    }
  });
```

Pass `onSortEnd` handler into sortable:

```
<SortableList items={itemList} onSortEnd={onSortEnd} />
```

**Mutation should have `update` handler (`writeQuery` - read docs) to force query update/rerendering.** Not quite required in this case (array already sorted in sortable, we're updating local array, it will rerender) but it should be here (mutation fail/errors - handle `error` from `useMutation`).

Types are good ... but **api detects wrong type** ... **every item in array contains `__typename` property** ... iterate over `newListOrder` elements (f.e. using `.map()`) and remove `__typename`. It should be visible in `console.log(newListOrder)`.

Try backend/API in playground (`/graphiql`) ... try mutations **using variables** before coding frontend. Compare network requests/response details.

Comment: thank you very much for response xadm.  When I attempt to create the type as you have shown **input ListItemsInput: [ListItem]!** I get a server errror.  Should this input be written differently? (I have many more questions for you so please be patient!)

Comment: see update, check passed variables, network request, try mutation in playground.

Comment: hey @xadm check out my recent issue.  I am getting Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400.  I also attempted to use the mutation in the playground but it wouldnt let me press play!  Something is of issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692553/why-am-i-receiving-status-code-400-when-passing-array-of-objects-as-parameter-of

Comment: remove `__typename` as described in answer

Comment: playground problem - defined variables (input content) object below query?